# If $a_n$ is divergent, then $f(a_n)$ is divergent

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose $f(x)$ is strictly increasing on $\mathbb R$ and $a_n$ is divergent. Then sequence $f(a_n)$ is also divergent.

How to prove that this is false? Actually, a counterexample will suffice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $a_n$ is increasing, then $f(a_n)$ is increasing thus convergent if and only if bounded. So you need $f(x)$ to be bounded.

This leads to $f(x)=\arctan(x), a_n=n$.

Answer (score 3):

Take $f(x)=-e^{-x}$ and $a_n=n$ and you have a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

You can take $f(x)=\text{e}^x$ and $a_n=n^2(n-\sqrt{n^2+1})$. Indeed $$a_n\to -\infty,~~f(a_n)\to 0$$

Comment: $\overset{+}{+}_+^+$